# Why is this encryption function outputting my numbers as letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on this encryption program, basic overview is that the function shifts 2 letters backward on the alphabet if letter inputted is uppercase, otherwise it goes up 2 on the alphabet, but for some reason, when I enter a number it outputs a letter. How do I make it to just output the number inputted without converting it into a letter?

```
def text_encrypt(plain_text):
encrypted = ''
for i in range(len(plain_text)):
    if plain_text[i] == ' ':
        encrypted = encrypted + plain_text [i] 
    elif plain_text[i].isupper():
        encrypted = encrypted + chr((ord(plain_text[i])-2-65)%26+65)
    else:
        encrypted = encrypted + chr((ord(plain_text[i])+2-97)%26+97)
return encrypted

#Testing code

text_plain = input("What would you like Encrypted?:")
plain_text = text_encrypt(text_plain)
print("Encrypted text: {}".format(plain_text))

#Sample Output: What would you like Encrypted?: One 1 
      Prints: Mpg g   #I need it to print Mpg 1
```

Comment: You're not doing any checks for numbers in your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your else to elif to detect lowercase characters also. Else case should be default of putting the character without changing.

```
    if plain_text[i].isupper():
        encrypted = encrypted + chr((ord(plain_text[i])-2-65)%26+65)
    elif plain_text[i].islower():
        encrypted = encrypted + chr((ord(plain_text[i])+2-97)%26+97)
    else:
        encrypted = encrypted + plain_text [i]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have skipped encryption for spaces. Similarly, you can skip encrypting digits.
isdigit() method can be used to check if a character/string is digit or not.

```
def text_encrypt(plain_text):
encrypted = ''
for i in range(len(plain_text)):
    if plain_text[i].isdigit() or plain_text[i] == ' ':
        encrypted = encrypted + plain_text [i] 
    elif plain_text[i].isupper():
        encrypted = encrypted + chr((ord(plain_text[i])-2-65)%26+65)
    else:
        encrypted = encrypted + chr((ord(plain_text[i])+2-97)%26+97)
return encrypted
```